# Maximum Sum Sub Array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I want to derive an approach in complexity `O(n)` or `O(1)` where i can find out the maximum sum of sub array when the array is repeated `k` times.

Let's say I have an array `a=[-5,2,2,2]`,  its maximum subarray  value is `6` and now when I repeat the same array again `a=[-5,2,2,2,-5,2,2,2]` the maximum sub array value is `7`.

I want a generalised approach when I repeat this array k  times in my problem.

So please anyone can guide me the approach of doing this problem with their solution.One more thing I only understand `python` language so please anyone help me out

Comment: Isn't the maximum sub array of your second example 12 and not 11? If that is the case and you don't care about order, why don't you just sum all all values > 0 in the original array and multiply by k?

Comment: Isn't it `7` for `[-5,2,2,2,-5,2,2,2]`?

Comment: So you want someone to come up with an algorithm, write the code and just hand it to you? Very nice, I would like a new car with that.

Comment: That being said, your sub-list will always be framed by the edges of your list or negative numbers, so it is actually quite simple to check all the combinations. I doubt you can get `O(1)` ever, and `O(n)` will definitely not be a naive interpretation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sir i just need your guidance to approach this question and please give some valuable hint

Comment: I think my hint was quite valuable. If you think about it for just a moment you will realize that it is practically a solution.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sir please make me more clear by giving me a small example...

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. At least think of an algorithm and write it in prose or pseudo code.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for a general solution for the maximum sequential sum in a sequence of integers, or for the max sum in a repeated sequence of specifically `-5, 2, 2, 2`? I would have to bill you for the former, but I can show you an O(1) algorithm for the latter. You should still put some thought into it and at least write down a conceptual solution.

Comment: @MadPhysicist the information in your hint is quite obvious. As the value of k can be very huge we can not check for those all combination. A valuable hint might point out something in direction where we will be taking advantage of the fact that if we know max sum sub-array for an array now that is repeated k times how we gonna find it?

Comment: @quintin. If the problem is specifically about the repeated sub array and you understand Enugu why the second sum is 7, what is confusing at that point?

Comment: @MadPhysicist max sum subset of [-5,2,2,2,-5,2,2,2] is [2,2,2,-5,2,2,2] = 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the highest sum of substring including the rightmost element and call it `sumR`. Then do the same but with the leftmost element and call it `sumL`. Then calculate the sum of the whole array and call it sumT. Finally, calculate the highest sum of a substring without iterations and call it `sumS`.

Now, given `k` repetitions, we have three candidates for maximum:`sumS`, `sumL+sumR` and `sumR+(k-1)*sumT+sumL`

However, there is a catch. If `sumL` or `sumR` is less than zero this will not work. So we calculate `sumLong = (k-t)*sumT + max(0, sumR) + max(0, sumL)`.

There are now three possible candidates:

- `sumS` if the maximum is inside the boarders. Example: `[-10,2,3,-9]`
- `sumL+sumR` if the maximum is across exactly one repetition. Example: `[1,-10,1]`
- `sumLong` if the maximum includes the full repetitions: `[2,3,4]`

Note that which candidate is the real maximum does not only depend on the array. It also depends on the value of `k`. The examples I listed are arrays that does not depend on `k`.

According to Wikipedia, it's easy to calculate `sumS` in O(n), and since all the other calculations is even simpler and only has to be done once, it's O(n) as a total. Here is the code:

```
def max_subarray(A):
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane%27s_algorithm_(Algorithm_3:_Dynamic_Programming)
    max_ending_here = max_so_far = A[0]
    for x in A[1:]:
        max_ending_here = max(x, max_ending_here + x)
        max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
    return max_so_far

def maxR(A):
    cm = sum_so_far = A[-1]
    for i in range(0, len(A)-1)[::-1]:
        sum_so_far = sum_so_far + A[i]
        cm = max(cm, sum_so_far)
    return cm

def maxL(A):
    cm = sum_so_far = A[0]
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        sum_so_far = sum_so_far + A[i]
        cm = max(cm, sum_so_far)
    return cm

def max_subarray_rep(A,k):
    sumS=max_subarray(A)
    if(k<1):
        return sumS
    sumL=maxL(A)
    sumR=maxR(A)
    if(k==1):
        return max(sumS, sumR+sumL)
    sumT=sum(A)
    sumLong = (k-1)*sumT + max(0, sumL) + max(0, sumR)
    return max(sumLong, sumR+sumL, sumS)
```

`max_subarray_rep` contains a few redundant lines, but those are for educational purposes, to make it easier to understand the thought behind.

Doing this in O(1) is impossible. I would also be willing to bet a lot of money that it is impossible to go below O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the maximum subarray in O(n) in the most general case:

```
def max_subarray(A):
    solve = A[0]
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(A)):
         sum = sum + A[i]
         if sum > solve:
               solve = sum
         if sum < 0:
               sum = 0
     return solve
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I could get which solved all my test cases.Please rectify if it contains any error or limitations.

```
def maxSubArraySum(a,size):

max_so_far =a[0]
curr_max = a[0]

for i in range(1,size):
    curr_max = max(a[i], curr_max + a[i])
    max_so_far = max(max_so_far,curr_max)

return max_so_far


for i in range(int(input())):

a,b=input().split()
a,b=[int(a),int(b)]
l=list(map(int,input().split()))
s1=maxSubArraySum(l,a)
s2=maxSubArraySum(l*2,a*2)
s3=maxSubArraySum(l*3,a*3)
sumi=sum(l)
if a==len(l):
    if b==1 :
        print (s1) 
    elif b==2:
        print (s2) 
    else:
        if s1==s2 :
            print (s2) 
        elif s1!=s2 :
            if s2==s3:
                print (s2) 
            else:
                print (max(s2+(b-2)*sumi,s1+(b-1)*sumi))
```